# Can boot partitions have a one to many relationship with root partitions? How much do boot partitions depend on root ones?

Tags: boot, raspberry-pi, root

I’m doing a project on my Raspberry Pi where I’m trying to have my root partition exist on a thumb drive.  Multiple thumb drives, actually. So all I have to do to go from one work space to another is plug in a new USB and reboot.

But this could really only work if the boot partition rarely changes, and does not know much more about the root partition than how to start up the OS.

Can this work? Do boot partitions care only about a few simple pieces of the root which can easily be kept the same for all, or do the two evolve together and become entangled?

I am running Raspian and intending to have multiple versions of the root system for it all used (one at a time) by the same boot.

Comment: Well, yes that would be preferable, but it's not something that can be done on a Pi.

What I can do is make a bootable SD that gets it's root partition from USB.

Comment: And then from there I could make a lot of different versions of root that do different things while all being based on the same foundation (Raspian in this case)

Comment: Perhaps.  I was hoping that this was more or less independent of any distro.  I'm hoping that boot systems are by definition independent of the OS except in the way the initiate it, which the internet kind of says they are, but not explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to my knowledge, this is completely possible!

> What you wanna do is to copy the root partition over to a USB
>   stick and then change the `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/cmdline.txt` to make it boot from the external drive instead of the second partition on the SD card.

If found a tutorial, but unfortunately it's not on English, so I will try to explain the procedure in my own words.

1. Reboot the Pi with the only external drive being the USB stick (this way we avoid having different drive-numbers on each bootup, since unique drive IDs are not possible if you wanna swap the USB sticks later).
2. Get the drive-number via `sudo blkid`. There should be only one which looks like this: `/dev/sda1`.
3. By using the command `mount` we can see if it has been automatically mounted. If it is not listed, proceed with the next step. If it is, run `sudo umount /dev/sda1` (correct for different numbers, if they are not the same) to unmount the USB stick.
4. Next we want to format the USB stick to have the correct file-system for the Debian root partition, which is preferably `ext4`. You can do this by running the command: `sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda1`.
5. After this, we need to (re)mount the USB stick on a temporary location to copy over the root partition from the SD card. We do this by running: `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`. (If the command complains about `/mnt` not existing, create a folder with that name by running: `sudo mkdir /mnt` and try again.
6. Now it's time to copy all the data from the root partition by first switching to the top directory with: `cd /` and then running this tar-command: `sudo tar cf - * --exclude /mnt/* | ( cd /mnt; sudo tar xfp -)`. It is probably not the most compact solution but it worked for me. Keep in mind that this might take a while, depending on the speed of your SD card and USB drive.
7. Next we need to change the `/etc/fstab` which contains the drives that are to be mounted on bootup by running `sudo nano /mnt/etc/fstab`. (**Notice that this is on the USB stick, since we added `/mnt`.**)
   You need to change the corresponding lines to make them look like this:

> `/dev/mmcblk0p1  /boot           vfat    defaults           0       0`
>   `/dev/sda1       /               ext4    defaults,noatime   0       0`

8. Finally we need to tell the boot partition on the SD card to boot from the USB drive instead. But first it is probably a good idea to make a backup of the file that we are going to change now, before we commit on making the switch, by running: `sudo cp /boot/cmdline.txt /boot/cmdline.txt.save`.
9. Run `sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt` to enter `nano` for changing the boot parameters on the first partition of the SD card. Basically we need to change the entry for the root partition to the USB drive. The tutorial offers this to be entered there (1 line):

   > `dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 root=/dev/sda1 rootfstype=ext4 noatime quiet rootwait loglevel=1 zram.num_devices=2`

   You can read into what those parameters mean [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_cmdline.txt).

   Now save and exit `nano` and at the next reboot, your Raspberry Pi should boot from the USB stick, but of course the SD card is still required, as you already mentioned.

As long as the USB drive is the only drive (apart from the SD card) at bootup, this should work. You have to have it somewhat dynamic and I don't see any other way of referring to the drive other than using `/dev/diskX`.

Edit: I forgot to mention that you need to duplicate the USB drive after you are done or do the same steps with other installations onto other drives. If the Raspian version including the installed packages are all the same, I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

The `/boot` partition is pretty basic and the line I mentioned in 9. is basically all it does. It just needs to hand it off to the correct partition with the correct file-system and it should work.

I hope this was helpful to you.

---

For the German-speaking people I will leave the source link here: [Source](http://raspberry.tips/raspberrypi-tutorials/raspberry-pi-sd-karte-durch-usb-stick-ersetzen/).

Comment: Yes, this totally was helpful.  Can you add this link https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=44177 to your answer for future searchers.  I'm still a little hesitant about whether or not boot has any other dependencies on root, but I can run some tests and have it verified by the end of the day.

Thank you!

Comment: I think if you leave your comment here, people will see it if they need more info on the subject. I am happy that I was able to help you and I am willing to improve my answer if there should be any issues coming up.